# Esempi di uso di "stare agli scherzi"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, idioms

In un esercizio di italiano ho trovato la frase seguente:

> È un tipo allegro che ama divertirsi, è uno che **sta agli scherzi**, abbiamo passato una serata molto divertente!

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scherzo) ho trovato che "stare allo scherzo" significa

> adattarcisi, essere di spirito, non essere permaloso.

Mi piacerebbe però avere alcuni esempi di uso di questa espressione per poter capire meglio come possa utilizzarla. Me li potreste fare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non ci sono particolari varianti al contesto in cui tu hai trovato l'espressione.

Comunque alcuni esempi sono:

- tu non sai stare agli scherzi, sei troppo permaloso
- una persona amabile è ironica, non si prende troppo sul serio e soprattutto sa stare agli scherzi